# Asynctask alternative for Heavy Work (Adding lot of fragment in the UI)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, background-task

I am getting all the dates between two given dates and then creating fragments for each date in between. The problem is when I use Asynctask and put the method in the doinbackground sometime it works and sometime it doesn't.

Specially when I open Asynctask containing activity from another activity. But on button click inside activity it works with a progressbar.

```
public class WaitForLoad extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pro_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        pro_bar.setVisibility(GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        get_con_fro_sta_to_end(dat_ran_sta, dat_ran_end);
        return null;
    }
}
```

So according to Asynctask documentation it should be 3 sec. But if I put a entire year in the method it takes about 8 sec to load or so.

So is there any workthrough Asynctask or Can you suggest me an example alternative Like maybe using a handler or so.

Comment: Im not exactly sure what you are asking, async tasks should be able to do the job correctly, you could consider doing multiple async tasks.

Comment: Firstly, make sure that you understand that you should not work with the UI in background threads, only in a main thread. So now it is not clear what exactly you are doing in background. Probably it could make sense to use multiple background threads for your task to improve it's speed (as modern devices nowadays have at least 2 CPU cores, which enables you to run at least 2 threads in paralel). Also make sure that you really need to load that *whole year* at once. Probably you need to load only some part of it.

Comment: So how do I work with UI in main thread. @VladyslavMatviienko

How do I use progressbar with main thread completes work

Comment: you do that correctly in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're changing Interface from your "*get_con_fro_sta_to_end()*" method...This is not allowed from a Background Thread and then it should be changed somehow.

AsyncTasks have the "*void onProgressUpdate()*" that is used to execute code in the UiThread/MainThread every time "*publishProgress()*" is called from "*doInBackground()*".

DoInBackground() should NOT touch Interface but just prepare Data/Things to be displayed using "*onPostExecute()*" (which runs code in the UiThread/MainThread)